# Wifi doesn't work on Ubuntu 13.10 in ASUS U32U Laptop

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.10, ath9k

i'd installed ubuntu 12.04 but i could have the wireless adapter working during the install assistant, but when i started the first time appears the message wireless adapter connection closed. So i've decide to go to 13.10, after so many attempts to make it work, but the problem with 13.10 it's still the same i get this message when i use rfkill command:

```
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

2: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

The command `rfkill` doesn't do anything. I try to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> buttons but only works the first time. And appears the option activate wireless in the connection manager.

But if i press the option with the mouse either with the function keys it change again to hard blocked.
I'll tried also changing the configuration file for my driver card which uses the ath9k driver. Adding this line:

```
options ath9k  bt_coex_active=0
```

Thank you.

Comment: supend the session and open again....and the wifi gonna work ...srry my english

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
rfkill unblock all
```

This solves often all rfkill issues.